# Ruby on rails scope like OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I write these two scopes in one, with an OR. Like either of them can be true.

```
scope :search_language, lambda {|y| where(["language LIKE ?", "#{y}"])}
scope :search_published, lambda {|y| where(["published LIKE ?", "#{y}"])}
```

Comment: You can add as `scope :search_language_or_published, lambda {|y| where(["language Like ? or published Like ?", "#{y}", "#{y}"]) }`

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the two into a single query as:

```
scope :language_or_published, lambda { |y| where('language like ? or published like ?', y, y) }
```

or the newer form of lambda(post Ruby1.9):

```
scope :language_or_published, ->(y){ where('language like ? or published like ?', y, y) }
```